# Is there a way to ensure at compile time that certain fields in an immutable object are set whilst keeping role of the arguments clear?

Tags: java, immutability

I'm experimenting with ways of creating immutable objects. The following builder objects
are quite attractive because they keep the role of the arguments clear. However I would like
to use the compiler to verify that certain fields are set, like with the `Immutable()` constructor invocation. `StrictImmutableBuilder` provides those checks, but is rather noisy. Is there some way to get the same checks but with the form of `LaxImmutableBuilder`? Perhaps using annotations?

```
public class Immutable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Immutable("13272873C", 23, false);
        // nice but what where those arguments?

        new LaxImmutableBuilder() {{
            refCode("13272873C");
            age(23);
            subscribed(false);
        }}.build();
        // now I know what each value represents
        // but what if I forgot to set one?

        new StrictImmutableBuilder() {
            public String refCode() { return "13272873C"; }

            public int age() { return 23; }

            public boolean subscribed() { return false; }
        }.build();
        // now I'm forced to set each field, but now 
        // we have the extra noise of "return"
        // and also "public" if we want to use
        // this outside the current package

        // is there another way? maybe using annotations?
    }

    private final String refCode;
    private final int age;
    private final boolean subscribed;

    public String getRefCode() {
        return refCode;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public boolean isSubscribed() {
        return subscribed;
    }

    public Immutable(String a, int b, boolean c) {
        this.refCode = a;
        this.age = b;
        this.subscribed = c;
    }

}

abstract class StrictImmutableBuilder {
    public abstract String refCode();

    public abstract int age();

    public abstract boolean subscribed();

    public Immutable build() {
        return new Immutable(refCode(), age(), subscribed());
    }
}

abstract class LaxImmutableBuilder {

    private String refCode;
    private int age;
    private boolean subscribed;

    protected void refCode(String refCode) {
        this.refCode = refCode;
    }

    protected void age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected void subscribed(boolean subscribed) {
        this.subscribed = subscribed;
    }

    public Immutable build() {
        return new Immutable(refCode, age, subscribed);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the pattern I use:

```
class YourClass {
  // these are final
  private final int x;
  private final int y;

  private int a;
  private int b;

  // finals are passed into the constructor
  private YourClass(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public static class Builder {
    // int x, int y, int a, int b
    // whatever's final is passed into constructor
    public Builder(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
    // a and b are optional, so have with() methods for these
    public Builder withA(int a) {
      this.a = a;
      return this;
    }
    public Builder withB(int b) {
      this.b = b;
      return this;
    }
    public YourClass build() {
      YourClass c = new YourClass (x, y);
      c.a = a;
      c.b = b;
      return c;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1: I do similarly, but rather than write the builder I generate it from the base, immutable class. This helps keep the classes consistent.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm guessing you use a tool to do this generation, if so which one?

Comment: Thanks! It's a good pattern if your objects have optional properties. Inner class also helps people find the builder for a given type, I guess.

Comment: I've set up an IntelliJ live template, so when I hit "b" "tab", it auto-generates the with() method for me, making it pretty straightforward to write these things

Answer (score 0):

there is this trick: Type-safe Builder Pattern

http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-java/

but that's just too crazy.

Comment: Thanks. Nice find. I'm almost crazy enough to use it! :) But it doesn't really scale to lots of arguments.